# Find largest char that occured double times in sequence

Tags: java, string, loops, char, iteration

my method findLargestDoubledChar takes in a string, and returns char c when c is the largest char that appears next to it's identical code. For example: `findLargestDoubledChar(look)` returns `o` and `findLargestDoubledChar(aaxx)` returns `x`. When there is no doubles, it's supposed to return `'\u0000'` I have spent hours toying with this code and this is what I have. Where am I going wrong?

```
public static char findLargestDoubledChar(String string){

        char largestDoubleChar = '\u0000';
        String doubleChars = "";

        char[] stringArray = string.toCharArray();

        for(int x = 0; x < stringArray.length - 1; x++) {
            for (int j = x + 1; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                if(stringArray[x] == stringArray[j]) {
                    System.out.println("Found Double!");
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < doubleChars.length(); i++) { //find largest of doubleChars
            if (doubleChars.charAt(i) >= largestDoubleChar) {
                largestDoubleChar = doubleChars.charAt(i);
            } else {
                largestDoubleChar = '\u0000';
                continue;
            }
        }



        return largestDoubleChar;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're iterating over doubleChars in the second loop when it's being set to an empty string. Maybe something like this would work better:

```
public static char findLargestDoubledChar(String string){

    char largestDoubleChar = '\u0000';
    String doubleChars = "";

    char[] stringArray = string.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (stringArray[i] == stringArray[i + 1]) {
            System.out.println("Found Double!");
            if (stringArray[i] > largestDoubleChar) largestDoubleChar = stringArray[i];
        }
    }

    return largestDoubleChar;
}
```

Comment: Oops, you have a left-over `doubleChars`. Still: +1

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

1. The inner loop isn't needed for the first loop.
2. You aren't storing the doubled char when you find it.
   Example answer from modifying yours:

   '   public static char findLargestDoubledChar(String string){

   ```
   char largestDoubleChar = '\u0000';
   String doubleChars = "";

   char[] stringArray = string.toCharArray();

   for(int x = 0; x < stringArray.length - 1; x++) {
       if (stringArray[x]==stringArray[x+1]){
           System.out.println("Found Double");
           doubleChars= doubleChars+ stringArray[x];

       }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < doubleChars.length(); i++) { //find largest of doubleChars
       if (doubleChars.charAt(i) >= largestDoubleChar) {
           largestDoubleChar = doubleChars.charAt(i);
       } else {
           largestDoubleChar = '\u0000';
           continue;
       }
   }



   return largestDoubleChar;
   ```

   }'

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single statement like this, which also supports Unicode characters from the supplemental planes, such as emojis.

```
public static String findLargestDoubledChar(String input) {
    return Character.toString(Pattern.compile("(.)\\1").matcher(input)
            .results().mapToInt(r -> r.group(1).codePointAt(0)).max().orElse('\0'));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(findLargestDoubledChar("look"));
System.out.println(findLargestDoubledChar("aaxx"));
System.out.println(findLargestDoubledChar(""));
```

*Output*

```
o
x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern DOUBLE_PAT = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1");

public static char findLargestDoubledChar(String string){
    return DOUBLE_PAT.matcher(string).results()
        .map(x -> x.group().charAt(0))
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse('\u0000');
}
```